# Cleaner error handling in Foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, try-catch

I have a few foreach loops happening. What's happening is, I am getting a list of flights froma  GPS device. So the first loop, I am parsing a string of header details for n number of flights.

Then, foreach flight, I query a device to get the raw GPS data.

So:

```
    foreach(var flight in flightList)
{
   var samples = GetRawGPSDataIntoAString();
   foreach(var line in samples)
   {
      var line = splitTheSampleIntoAListOfStrings();
      foreach(var sampleSection is line)
      {
         DoSomeStuff();
      }
   }
}
```

My problem is that if I detect an issue with something within the inner loops, I want to log some data to a log file (done), then exit the inner loop, as the 'line' is malformed.

I then want to exit the 2nd loop as well, as it's now pointless to continue with the sample. I then want to inform the user that a flight had invalid data, and ask if they want to coninue loading the rest of the flights. If they say yes, I want the next outer loop to go to the next one.

I currently have no error handling... so, I am going to put a try/except around the areas where I know it can fail... especially where I split the strings (comma seaparated), and then do dangerous things like, 'string gpsCoord = line[2]'. If there was an error during the 'split', then it's possible to get an index out of range issue. (I agree, I can check first that there are enough items in 'line', which I will do, but I am unsure how to abort two 'foreach' loops at once, returning control to the outer loop.

Hope I am making a bit os sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you're dealing with terminating multiple nested loops, it's often best to put each loop in its own function:

```
private static bool ProcessLine(string line)
{
    try
    {
        var sampleSections = splitTheSampleIntoAListOfStrings();
        foreach( var sampleSection in line )
        {
            DoSomeStuff();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch( SomeException ex )
    {
        LogError(ex);
        return false;
    }
}

private static void ProcessSamples(FlightType flight)
{
    var samples = GetRawGPSDataIntoAString(flight);
    foreach( var line in samples )
    {
        if( !ProcessLine(line) )
            return;
    }
}

private static void ProcessFlights()
{
    foreach( var flight in flightList )
    {
        ProcessSamples(flight);
    }
}
```

This makes it very easy to break out of some nested loops and continue others without having to use messy constructs like exit flags. The code also is easier to read because of the reduced nesting level.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It sounds like you're interested in the ability to "re-throw" an exception:</strike>

```
foreach(var flight in flightList)
{
   try {
       var samples = GetRawGPSDataIntoAString();
       foreach(var line in samples)
       {
          var line = splitTheSampleIntoAListOfStrings();
          foreach(var sampleSection in line)
          {
             try {
                 DoSomeStuff();
             }
             catch(Exception ex) {
                 log(ex);
                 throw; // <--- HERE, we didn't solve the problem
                        // so we let the exception reach the next catch
             }
          }
       }
       catch (ContinuableException ex2) { /* ignore and keep trying */ }
   }
}
```

I would split this up into multiple functions though, two try/catch blocks in one function is too many.  Here's another approach without rethrowing:

```
foreach(var flight in flightList)
{
    var samples = GetRawGPSDataIntoAString();
    ProcessSamples(samples);
}

ProcessSamples(samples) // fix the return type and parameter type, of course
{
   foreach(var line in samples)
   {
      var line = splitTheSampleIntoAListOfStrings();
      foreach(var sampleSection in line)
      {
         try {
             DoSomeStuff();
         }
         catch(Exception ex) {
             log(ex);
             return; // exits two loops at once
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
bool exitFlag = false;
foreach(var flight in flightList)
{
   foreach(var line in samples)
   {
      if(exitFlag){
               exitFlag = false;
               break;
      }
      var samples = GetRawGPSDataIntoAString();
      var line = splitTheSampleIntoAListOfStrings();
      foreach(var sampleSection is line)
      {
         try{
             DoSomeStuff();
          }
          catch(*the exception you expect* e){
                 Log(e); // do some logging
                 exitFlag = true;   
                 break;
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still want the outer loop to continue.. so, I want it to do a 'next item, please' - not terminate the loop completely. Would this be achieved?

Comment: That doesn't seem to exit the second loop, like the question specifies.

Comment: @cdotlister if you want to continue with the outer loop, then skip the exitFlag and just do a `break` inside catch `block`. see http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c78970ee-eb2a-4a0b-a0e1-d89b9c79e938/view-source

Comment: @Bala: I think you missed the fact that there are THREE nested loops here.

Comment: @Ben Yes indeed :). Moved things a little bit to fix.

Comment: You need to reset exitflag inside the first foreach loop, or it will not be reset to false after you set it to true once.

Comment: @Scott I have it resetting in the second loop just before `break` which should be fine as well.